# Finding the minimum value of a summation of tuples using the least squares method

Tags: derivatives, summation, least-squares

This is an exam question from a previous year that I have not been able to figure out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Given are the tuples (1,2),(2,1),(3,1)
$$\varepsilon^{2} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} (y_i - a \cdot x_i)^{2}$$

For what value $a\in\mathbb{R}$ is $\varepsilon$ minimal.

My work so far:

$\varepsilon = q(a) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sqrt{(y_i - a \cdot x_i)^{2}}$

$q'(a) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{2}((y_i-ax_i)^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\cdot 2(y_i-ax_i)\cdot(-x_i)$

$q'(a) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{(-x_iy_i+ax_i^2)}{(y_i-ax_i)^2}$

$q''(a) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{(x_i^2)(y_i-ax_i)^2-2(-x_iy_i+ax_i^2)(-x_iy_i+x_i^2)}{2(y_i-ax_i)^4}$

$q''(a) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{(x_i^2)(y_i^2 -2ax_iy_i+ax_i^2)-2(x_i^2y_i^2-ax_i^3y_i + ax_i^4 - x_i^3y_i)}{2(y_i-ax_i)^4}$

$q''(a) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{(x_i^2y_i^2 -2ax_i^3y_i+ax_i^4)-2x_i^2y_i^2+2ax_i^3y_i -2ax_i^4 + 2x_i^3y_i)}{2(y_i-ax_i)^4}$

$q''(a) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{x_i^2y_i^2 -2ax_i^3y_i+ax_i^4-2x_i^2y_i^2+2ax_i^3y_i -2ax_i^4 + 2x_i^3y_i)}{2(y_i-ax_i)^4}$

$q''(a) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{2x_i^3y_i-x_i^2y_i^2 -ax_i^4)}{2(y_i-ax_i)^4}$

At this point I would assume that $2x_i^3y_i < x_i^2y_i^2 + ax_i^4$ and therefore $q''(a)$ would be a monotonically falling function, thereby having no minimum. However, I don't know how to prove that other than to plug in the tuples.

Continuing on and trying to find the critical point:

$0 = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{(-x_iy_i+ax_i^2)}{(y_i-ax_i)^2}$

$0 = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{(-x_iy_i+ax_i^2)}{a^2x_i^2 + 2ax_iy_i + y_i^2}$

At this point I am at a loss as to how to factor out $a$.

Comment: $\epsilon$ is minimal in magnitude when $\epsilon^2$ is minimal.  So simply differentiate the original expression (no need for a square root) with respect to $a$, find the $a$ which makes the derivative $0$ and check it is actually a minimum

Comment: Thank you! That clears up a lot. Should I leave up this post?